# How to select between, for example, between 6:15 and 7:15? Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I want to query data that happened between 6:15 and 7:15, 7:15:01 and 8:15 and so forth. So far I am only able to do the following:

```
Select *
From table
Where datepart(hh, t_stamp) = 7  
  and datepart(day, t_stamp) = day(getdate())
```

I am selecting all data that happens between 7:00 and 7:59:59....

I tried googling it. Found something using unix_timestamp, but that does not work in Microsoft SQL Server. I've been wrecking my brain but as a SQL noob (I am used to "ladder logic" in PLC programming) this is way out of my comfort zone.

Comment: What is the data type of the `t_stamp` column?

Comment: The datatype is datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for fetching the data between a specific time, let's say 06:15 to 07:15 for any date, then convert the datetime to time and use it in the where clause.

**Query**

```
select * from your_table_name
where cast(t_stamp as time) between '06:15:00' and '07:15:00';
```

If you need it only for today's date, then add that condition too in the Where clause.

```
select * from your_table_name
where cast(t_stamp as time) between '06:15:00' and '07:15:00'
and cast(t_stamp as date) = cast(getdate() as date);
```